# Conditional formatting inconsistent using MATCH in a custom formula

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have 2 cells `A1` and `B1` that contain the same values.  I want to create a conditional formatting rule using the custom formula `=MATCH(A1,B1)` that colours both cells green.

This sometimes works on other cell pairs but other times it simply doesn't work.

Note that the cells have a custom number format that adds a letter and a semi-colon before the numbers.

Let me know what I am doing wrong.

**3 pairs, 2 pairs worked, `Q3` & `R3` didn't:**
[image: 3 cell couples, 2 cell couple worked but the last one on the right didnt.]

**My conditional formatting:**
[image: here is my conditional formatting]

Answer (score 1):

## RULE

In the formula below, the [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en) function's `search_type` argument was changed to `0` (exact match) and it's `range` argument is now calculated by offsetting the `search_key` column by `1` or `-1`, depending if it is the left or right column in its column pair

```
# Apply to range
M3:R55

# Custom formula
=MATCH(M3,OFFSET(M3,0,IF(ISODD(COLUMN($M3))=ISODD(COLUMN()),1,-1)),0)
```

---

## ISSUES

The main issue with your approach was tied to how relative refferences are handled.  Additionally, the type of match was incorrectly set.

#### Relative References

The cell references in your formula are relative. When a conditional formatting rule is applied to a range of cells,  relative references are updated for each cell based on its position in relation to the first cell (topmost-leftmost) in the rule's `Apply to range`.

Offsetting your formula's row references has no undesired effect, however, offsetting the column references by an odd number (every other) causes the [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en) function's `range` argument to reference a cell from a completely different column pair than was intended.

One can see the same behavior by placing the formula `=MATCH(M3,N3,0)` in `M4` and then copying it to `N4` and `O4`.

- In `N4` the formula `=MATCH(N3,O3,0)` will not work as intended. It will attempt to match a value from `N3` which is in the right column of a pair, with a value from `O3`, which is in the left column of a completely different pair.
- In `O4` the formula `=MATCH(O3,P3,0)` will behave similarly to the original formula in `M4`.  It will attempt to match the value from `O3` which is in the left column of a pair, with a value from `P3` which is in the right column of the same pair .

#### search_type

The original formula's [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en) function had the `search_type` argument set to `1` (default) which specifies searching the `range` for the largest value that is less than or equal to the `search_key`, while also assuming that the `range` is sorted in ascending order.  It should have been set to `0` for an exact match.

The original formula was succeeding half the time, however the default `search_type` in combination with the actual data, was giving the false impression that it succeeding more than 50% of the time.  The expected formatting would have been applied in some cases where the wrong cells were being compared, and where their  values didn't match.

For example, the formula in `M3` when applied to `N3` becomes `=MATCH(N3,O3)` which would return TRUE in the rule because `N3>=O3`

```
=MATCH(N3,O3)   // search_type: 1         
=MATCH(58,8)    // 
=1              // 58 >= 8 (8 matched in position 1)

=MATCH(N3,O3,0)   // search_type: 0
=MATCH(58,8,0)   
=#N/A             // No Match found
```

---

## EXPLANATION

The conditional formatting rule is applied to a contiguous range of column pairs, with each pair comprised of a left and a right column, eg. `M3:R55`

1. If the [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en) function's `search_key` is located in a left column, its `range` argument should be the cell [OFFSET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en) one column right of the `search_key`.

   - `OFFSET(M3,0,1)`
2. If the `search_key` is in a right column, then the `range` should be the cell [OFFSET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en) one column left of the `search_key`

   - `OFFSET(M3,0,-1)`
3. The first column in the rule's `Apply to range` is necessarily a left column.  If that column is odd-numbered, *all* left columns will be odd-numbered.  If it's even-numbered, *all* left columns will be even-numbered.
4. Therefore, a test of the first column with the [ISODD](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093491?hl=en) function, and the same test on the curent column, would necessarily **both succeed** or **both fail** if the current column is a left column.
   For example,

```
# First Column is M, current cell is Q3

=ISODD(COLUMN($M3))=ISODD(COLUMN())
=ISODD(13)=ISODD(17)
=TRUE=TRUE
=TRUE        // current col is left


# First Column is M, current cell is R3

=ISODD(COLUMN($M3))=ISODD(COLUMN())
=ISODD(13)=ISODD(18)
=TRUE=FALSE
=FALSE      // current col is right


# First Column is N, current cell is R3

=ISODD(COLUMN($N3))=ISODD(COLUMN())
=ISODD(14)=ISODD(18)
=FALSE=FALSE
=TRUE       // current col is left
```

5. All that remains is to populate the [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en) function's `range` argument by passing the `search_key` as the `cell_reference` of an [OFFSET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en) function, and setting `offset_rows` to `0`, and `offset_columns` to `1` or `-1` depending on the TRUE or FALSE outcome of the [ISODD](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093491?hl=en) tests comparison:

```
=MATCH(M3,OFFSET(M3,0,
  IF(ISODD(COLUMN($M3))=ISODD(COLUMN()),
    1,   // condition_true (current col is left)
    -1)) // condition_false (current col is right)
  ,0)
```

[image]